# Is it safe to reuse Faraday connection objects?

Tags: ruby, http, faraday

Is it safe to reuse [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) connection objects, or is it better to recreate them every time?

```
def connection
  @connection ||= Faraday.new('http://example.com') do |conn|
    conn.request :url_encoded
    # more configuration
  end
end
```

Comment: Related issue on faraday github: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/370

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/52e30bf8e8d79159f332088189cb7f7e536d1ba1/lib/faraday/connection.rb#L502

`connection.get` `.post` and all other methods duplicates params etc here.
It means each request shares nothing with each other and the parent Connection object.

It's safe to reuse.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's safe to reuse them (I have, a lot). I don't see it really covered one way or another in the [documentation](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) but the presence of "Per-request options" (as opposed to per-connection) at least implies that you can rely on making multiple requests with the same connection.